# More LValue Errors

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, indexing, lvalue

Below is a triple nested indexing scheme.  My pointer to an array of pointers is dereferenced on the commented line... in theory this should give me a pointer.   I subtract one from it and then reference it and reassign that to my pointer to the array of pointers.  But that line gives an lvalue error for the operand "&".

Let me be perfectly clear.  I want to both know why the error is occurring here AND get a method that works for assigning the address of the previous element in the array of pointers to my frame double pointer.

I will only accept full solutions that satisfy both criteria....

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct frame_s {
  double ** TestArrayPointer;
} frame_t;

main () {

  double * TestArray;
  double ** TestPointerArray;
  TestArray = new double [100];

  TestPointerArray = new double * [100];

  for (unsigned int Counter = 0; Counter<100; Counter++)
  {
     TestArray[Counter]=Counter;
     TestPointerArray[Counter]=&(TestArray[Counter]);
  }

  frame_t Frames[10];
  for (unsigned int Counter = 0; Counter<10; Counter++)
    Frames[Counter].TestArrayPointer = &(TestPointerArray[Counter*10]);

  //Move pointer to point at array position one back.
  Frames[2].TestArrayPointer=
      &(*(Frames[2].TestArrayPointer)-1); //error! here <--

  //OUTPUT Values...
  for (unsigned int Counter = 0; Counter<100; Counter++)
    std::cout << "P: " << TestPointerArray[Counter] << " V: " 
          << *(TestPointerArray[Counter]) << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged `c++` instead of the current `c` tag?

Comment: Please provide the actual compiler error.

Comment: error: invalid lvalue in unary ‘&’

Comment: you're right, I used new... it's not really central to the issue here, but I'm changing it.... the code in question could be done with malloc/printf, but I used new/cout so you're probably right.  I was going to argue it if it was just the cout, but the new tipped the scale in my mind (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Frames[2].TestArrayPointer=
  &(*(Frames[2].TestArrayPointer)-1);
```

Here both the dereferencing and then taking back the address is unnecessary. You can directly do -

```
Frames[2].TestArrayPointer = (Frames[2].TestArrayPointer)-1) ;
```

But this has a potential problems.

- What if the index is 0 ? Runtime error.
- What if the index is the last index ? Memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because the `-1` is applied after the `*`.  You can't take the address of the result of the subtraction operator - such is an *rvalue*, rather than an *lvalue* (an lvalue designates an actual object - an rvalue is just an ephemeral value).

Initially, `Frames[2].TestArrayPointer` points at the third `double *` in the array pointed to by `TestPointerArray`.  Presumably, you want to change it to point to the second `double *` in that array instead.  If so, you can simply change that line to:

```
Frames[2].TestArrayPointer = Frames[2].TestArrayPointer - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Frames[2].TestArrayPointer` has type `double**`

`*(Frames[2].TestArrayPointer)` has type `double*`

So `*(Frames[2].TestArrayPointer) - 1` is a temporary with type `double*`.  A temporary is an rvalue - you can't take the address of it.

I think what you want is:

```
&(*((Frames[2].TestArrayPointer)-1))
```

which is also a `double*`, but it's the one previous to `Frames[2].TestArrayPointer` rather than a temporary.

And if we get rid of 'canceling' operators and redundant parens:

```
Frames[2].TestArrayPointer - 1
```